# Java function app in azure using Asb queue trigger

Tags: java, azure, queue, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Can anyone share complete code for   java function app in azure  using  ASB queue trigger

Answer (score 0):

You can find all Java Azure function samples [here](https://github.com/damoodamoo/java-function-samples/tree/master/java-func-samples/src/main/java/com/damoo/samples).